# In my Website homepage I want to remove date which is written along author name

Tags: date

Kindly tell me how should I remove the date written alongside all posts in Homepage.

Comment: I can't see any dates on the homepage. Have you managed to resolve this yourself? If not, please provide more detail and show what you have tried and what research you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little dirty but fast solution is to hide it via css. add this code to custom css

```
.home .td-big-grid-post .td-post-date {
  display: none;
}
```

Better approach would be to find a template file or function responsible for this section and remove or change it...